# How can I customize the Angular JS UI Bootstrap date picker for picking days only?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/jeSOzpGVTJEEkHzCRHZP?p=preview) calendar to select **days of months**.

[image]

```
<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <uib-datepicker year-range="0" show-weeks="false" max-mode="month" ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></uib-datepicker>
</div>
```

I want to make the year disappear completely, making the calendar show the days of the months only. Also I have disabled the "show-weeks" option because for a "generic" year there are no fixed numbered weeks (their number depends on the year).

I have tried to play with the max-mode option, making it "month" but without success.

I wanted it to be like this:

[image]

and make it loop around if I reach December and press the "next" button, on in January if I press the "previous" button.

Another thing I would need was to make it able to select multiple days.

This calendar will be used to select birthdays, so since everyone has birthdays every year, it makes no sense to show the year in the calendar. In the end I just need to collect the list of day/month pairs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- Angular's datepicker does not support multiple date selection by default. However there is a [library](https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect) written by spongesuck that I believe may assist you.
- Formatting the selection title is as simple as changing the date-picker attribute as stated in their docs.

  ```
   <uib-datepicker ng-model='app.activeDate' multi-select='app.selectedDates' format-day-title="MMMM" show-weeks="false" year-range="1" select-range='{{app.type=="range"}}'></uib-datepicker>
  ```
- Enabling the arrows to only loop through 12 months arbitrary of a year could be made possible through a custom class but it makes more sense to me to just drop/manipulate the year before processing these dates. ie technically the datepicker is proceeding through theyears when we hit that right arrow button, but we choose to just not show the year.

Here's a sample of what you might be looking for. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n5S9MstNQb7lERyn8Lfe?p=preview)